# How to back on the same activity?

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

I have one activity which firstly show the  `<string-array name="main">`. This "main" array it include two items --> (Category and Manufacturer). I also defined `<string-array name="Category">` and `<string-array name="Manufacturer">` in `String.xml`, each of them contain five items.

When the "Category" item is clicked the items if *Category* are shown, and the same thing for *Manufacturer*. But here I have a problem, for example if firstly I click on the "Category" item it's items are shown but I can't getting back again to the "main" array which include the (Category and Manufacturer) items.

When I click "back" on my device the app is closed , because I'm working with same activity to show the different lists.

Is there any way without creating a new activity that allow me go back and show the "main" list with the back option?

main.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{

    ListView lv;
    String [] list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        list=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.main);

        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list));
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        switch(lv.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()){
        case "Category":
            list=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Category);
            lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list));
            break;

        case "Manufacturer":
            list=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Manufacturer);
            lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list));
            break;


        }

    }

}
```

String.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">ShaymaTest</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>

    <string-array name="main">
        <item >Category</item>
        <item >Manufacturer</item>

    </string-array><string-array name="Category">
        <item >Category</item>
        <item >Category</item>
        <item >Category</item>
        <item >Category</item>
        <item >Category</item>
    </string-array><string-array name="Manufacturer">
        <item >Manufacturer</item>
        <item >Manufacturer</item>
        <item >Manufacturer</item>
        <item >Manufacturer</item>
        <item >Manufacturer</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

Comment: You can override onBackPressed and make it do whatever you want.  Another possibility would be to use fragments.

Comment: As others suggested you can override your onBackPressed to achieve what you are looking for. But I need to tell you something: Don't create new adapters every time for changing the contents, Instead create a single adapter as instance variable and only change the items in adapter and call the adapter.notifyDatasetChanged() method.

Comment: Thanks @GabeSechan

Comment: Thank u @SanifSS for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare a variable to know the current status and override `onBackPressed` method like this

```
private boolean inSub = false;

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        inSub = true;
        switch(lv.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()){

[.....]

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (inSub){
            list=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.main);
            lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list));
            inSub = false;
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```